# An unbounded function whose square is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

> I want an example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to [0, \infty)$ which is unbounded but such that $f^2$ is uniformly continuous.

However much I try I am able to get only bounded functions like $\sin x$. We have $\sin^2 x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ because its derivative is bounded on $\mathbb R$. But how do I get an unbounded function satisfying the hypothesis? Please help.

Comment: Type this up using MathJax and I'll share a solution.

Comment: How about $\sqrt{|x|}$?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and also for editing my problem using MathJax. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any smooth unbounded function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)f'(x)$ is bounded will do. Proof: The derivative of $f(x)^2$ is $2f(x)f'(x),$ which is bounded. It is well known that any differentiable function with bounded derivative is Lipschitz, hence is uniformly continuous.

For example $f(x) = \ln (1+x^2)$ has this property.

Comment: Thank you for your help.